# Will Coffeescript ever adopt optional Types, similar to Typescript?

Tags: types, coffeescript, typescript

With the recent advent of Typescript and the *optional* static typing it asserts, Coffeescript developers are likely to feel missing out [those features](http://siek.blogspot.gr/2012/10/is-typescript-gradually-typed-part-1.html)

Is Coffeescript **able** and/or **likely** to adopt *optional* types in future versions and how would the syntax work ?

Comment: This question is two fold: **able** should answer to the technical feasibility, such as parsing, syntax, code transformation etc. **Likely** should answer to the direction the CS _team_ is likely to adopt regarding static typing

Answer (score 4):

The idea has been proposed and rejected several times. See e.g. [issue 1833](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1833).

There is a fork for this called [Contracts.coffee](http://disnetdev.com/contracts.coffee/).

Comment: Thank you, but contracts.coffee and this rejected suggestion, although useful at some cases, is not exactly what TypeScript offers. Optional static typing in TS aims at development time inference of types and errors, giving IDEs information for proper refactoring etc. This is the kind of functionality that 'd be ideal, and wouldn't create runtime overhead in size / speed